# Запуск нескольки node.js на одном сервере с разных IP

Tags: javascript, node.js, debian, steam

Приветствую, к примеру есть один сервер и куча дополнительных выделенных `IP` адресов. Как мне запустить несколько скриптов на `node.js` с разных `IP`? Ведь всегда при запуске node.js запускается с `default` ip.
Это будет не express и подобные серверные фреймворки, в которых можно указать IP. Для справки, будут использоваться библиотеки для steam.

Answer (score 1):

Поставить nginx. В нём слушать разные ip.

```
server {
    listen 192.168.0.100:80;
    ...
}
```

node.js скрипты запускать на разных портах, а в nginx переадресовывать запросы к разным ip на разные порты, на которых запущены node.js скрипты.

Comment: в моих скриптах node.js нету сервера в котором я могу выбрать порт для запуска. Так же нету доступа по ссылке, это не сайт. Это бот, который авторизуется в steam и принимает от него запросы, своими методами. Мне как-то нужно сделать что бы каждый бот был на разных ip адресах.